# Save setting during update

Tags: upgrade, mate

Could you tell me, I have Ubuntu Mate 16.04 LTS. The system is up-to-date until April this year, I am going to update the system to version 18.04 LTS.
Do I lose my private settings during updating?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "seeting." Do you mean **settings**? What do you mean by "private seeting? Are these your customization of the desktop (personal wallpaper, for example), the saved preferences for the software you use? If so, then **No! You won't lose them!!"**

Comment: It is difficult to say without further details. How will you upgrade to 18.04? Fresh install? From Update manager? Do you have a separate partition for your home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to use update manager. This one tells me that my system will be not up to dat soon. Private seeting I mean = all programs which I have installed now, colors of wallpaper ect.  and I do not want to have new programs